# Select the highest possible number of occurences in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to extract ip addresses with ports from a text.

But I don't know how to get the regular expression to capture the biggest-highest possible match of numbers (IP octets). For example from 209 and expression \d{1,3} to capture the whole 209 instead of just 9.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@".*(?<ip>(?:[12]?\d{1,2}\.){3}[12]?\d{1,2})\s*(?<port>\d{2,4}).*");
string textWithIPs = "209.90.238.251    3128    HTTPS   Anonymous   [United States Proxy] United States Washington  Renton  84.5%   58.240.224.186  80  HTTP    None    [China Proxy] China Jiangsu Nanjing 98.4%   ";

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(textWithIPs))
{
    MessageBox.Show("ip: " + m.Groups["ip"].Value + " port: " + m.Groups["port"].Value);
}
```

Expected output:

```
ip: 209.90.238.251 port: 3128
ip: 58.240.224.186 port: 80
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.*` at the beginning of your regex **consumes the text that you want to match**, and the `.*` at the end is is just redundant. Remove them and your code should work.

Your current regex may match a lone IP address without port number and split it up incorrectly. You can give it the input string `123.123.123.123` and the output will be IP being `123.123.123.1` and port number being `23`, which is incorrect<sup>1</sup>. I change `\s*` to `\s+` to fix this problem.

```
@"(?<ip>(?:[12]?\d{1,2}\.){3}[12]?\d{1,2})\s+(?<port>\d{2,4})"
```

Note that port numbers can range from 1 to 65535 (port 0 is reserved), so you may want to modify the regex for port from `(?<port>\d{2,4})` to `(?<port>\d{1,5})`.

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This is the output after you remove `.*` at the beginning. In your original regex, the problem is still there - the last 2 digits are still cut off to form the port number, which is incorrect.

Comment: @JoudicekJouda: Note that there are other problems in your regex that I point out in the latest edit.

Comment: Yes I found that too. But I believe the better would be: `@"(?<ip>(?:[12]?\d{1,2}\.){3}[12]?\d{1,2})\s*[\s:]\s*(?<port>\d{2,4})"` as the ip addresses are sometimes as a whole in the text (192.168.1.1:8080)